# React Native: Building a Progress Step Bar Component

Tags: react-native, components

How would you use a component to notify the user which step they are on? I have this setup like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const ProgressBar = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        <Bar />
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>1. Photo</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        <Bar />
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>2. Details</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        <Bar />
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>3. Price</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        <Bar />
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>4. Finish</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Bar = styled.View`
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  stepWrapper: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '25%',
  },
  stepText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 13,
  },
});
export default ProgressBar;
```

This outputs this:

[image]

But this page is supposed to be the 3rd step (3. Price). Everything is red because of the class name, but I was curious as to how to set it up so I can insert this component into each screen and passing a numeric prop of the step or something.

Maybe something like:

```
<ProgressBar step={3} />
```

And maybe in my component, I can change all the colors up to only 3rd element of `<Bar />`, or if there's a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4):

Proceeding with your objective let's make a component named ProgressBar, which takes the progress as a prop and shows the progress as UI

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ProgressBar = ({ step = 1 }) => {
  const stepArr = ['Photo', 'Details', 'Price', 'Finish'];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {stepArr.map((element, index) => (
        <View style={styles.singleStep}>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 2,
              backgroundColor: step < index + 1 ? 'red' : 'green',
              width: '100%',
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.singleTxt}>{`${index + 1}. ${element}`}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProgressBar;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  singleStep:{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' },
  singleTxt:{ marginTop: 10 }
});
```

Now import ProgressBar in every page and mentioned its progress like
 in Price page.

I think this is the easiest and elegant way. Please let me know in the comments if you found it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to use the great npm package for built-in support of stepper bar

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stepper-ui

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const ProgressBar = ({ step }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        {step === 1 ? <Bar /> : <BarGray />}
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>1. Photo</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        {step === 2 ? <Bar /> : <BarGray />}
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>2. Details</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        {step === 3 ? <Bar /> : <BarGray />}
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>3. Price</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.stepWrapper}>
        {step === 4 ? <Bar /> : <BarGray />}
        <Text style={styles.stepText}>4. Finish</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Bar = styled.View`
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const BarGray = styled.View`
  border: 1px solid gray;
`;



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  stepWrapper: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '25%',
  },
  stepText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 13,
  },
});
export default ProgressBar;
```